# How to change a drive letter dynamically on a .bat script

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, usb-drive

I'm currently working with an old script for a process that was in place before I took a look at it, the premise is to automatically create a folder and copy the contents of a flash drive into a C: drive.  Below is the portion of the script I am concerned with:

xcopy "E:\directory" "c:\directory" /s /y

This is the script as I have it now, currently I need to change the first directory entry almost every time I plug into a new device as the drive letter as it appears in the script is sometimes different then what is on the local device.  For example, the UBS drive would be D: on a laptop, but E: on most desktops, or some other letter in the case of a device with multiple peripherals.

Previously the script looked something like:

xcopy "...\directory" "c:\directory" /s /y

This doesn't function as the .bat file would come back with an inability to locate said directory on the UBS drive.  When I manually change the .bat file to hard set the USB drive letter everything flows fine, all directories copy and the subsequent scripts run fine.

My question, any ideas on how to set the xcopy script to recognize the dynamic USB drive letter and allow for copying without having to change the script on each device?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait a moment! Where is the batch file stored? Is it stored on the USB drive and executed from there with a double click or is it stored on a local hard disk drive? In case of the batch file is stored on the USB drive and executed from there with a double click, use `xcopy "\directory" "c:\directory" /s /y` because a path starting with a backslash is relative to __root of current drive__ or use `xcopy "%~d0\directory" "c:\directory" /s /y` because `%~d0` references the drive (letter plus colon) of first argument - the batch file. Or use `%~dp0` - drive and path of batch file ending with ``\``.

Answer (score 1):

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set evtDevice = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent")

Wscript.Echo "Waiting for events ..."
Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = evtDevice.NextEvent
    'report an event
    Wscript.Echo " Win32_Device Changed event occurred" & VBNewLine
    If objReceivedEvent.EventType = 1 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Config Changed" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 2 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Arrived" 

         Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Volume")
         For Each objItem in colItems
               If objitem.DriveType = 2 then
                        Wscript.Echo objItem.DriveType & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.driveletter

                        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
                        set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

                        Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(objitem.driveletter)
                        Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace("c:\test\")
                        Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
                        DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
                        Wscript.Echo "Finished Copying"
                        Wscript.sleep 2000

               End If
        Next


    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 3 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Left" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Computer Docked" 
    End If
Loop
```

This vbs script waits for a USB to be inserted then copies it to a folder.

Remove all the debugging `wscript.echo` lines. Change the destination folder.

It copies all attached USB drives.

Answer (score 0):

despite the previous answer from Noodles

```
@echo off

set "destDrive="
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %i in (`"wmic logicaldisk get caption, drivetype"`) do (
  if %%j EQU 2 set "destDrive=%%i"
)

if "%destDrive%" EQU "" (
  echo No pendrive found
) else (
  echo copying
  xcopy "%destDrive%\directory\*.*" "c:\directory\*.*" /s /y
  echo done...
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not modify the batch file to ask for the drive letter before the copy begins?

```
SET /P USB=Enter USB Drive Letter (C:, D:, E: etc):  
XCOPY "%USB%\directory" "C:\directory" /s /y
```